# ProperCase SSRS 2008 Within Footer

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to create a footer that is using `ProperCase` within SSRS 2008

I have tried

```
=Code.ProperCase(LCase(Fields!aField1.Value, "DataSet1"))
```

to use the `ProperCase` field within the footer but it is stating that I do not have the `text box` linked to a DataSet.

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem lies with the ProperCase function. However, when inserting a value from a dataset, outside the context of the dataset, you must specify what record to use. For example, to use the first record from the dataset in your page footer, you should write your expression like this:

```
=Code.ProperCase(LCase(First(Fields!aField1.Value, "DataSet1")))
```

In other words, the reference to "DataSet1" makes no sense in the LCase-function, which is just a simple string manipulation function. To reference the dataset, you must use one of the Aggregate functions (in this case, `First()`), which takes as second argument the name of the dataset in question.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that I might have to put the First part into the expression, I was just unsure where.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have written the `ProperCase` function yourself? There is a VBA function available in SSRS that allows you to change the case of a string and it's called `StrConv` which you could've used.

In your case you'd write: `StrConv(First(Fields!aField1.Value, "DataSet1"), vbStrConv.ProperCase)`

The other benefit of the `StrConv` function is that you can specify a localeID too if that is of any relevance.